# MigLayout two column vertical flow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, miglayout

I want a 2-column layout where I can specify which column to insert the next element into. 
It needs to grow automatically -- I don't want to specify the row.

So, for example, I want to say:

- add 4 elements in column 1
- add 3 elements in column 2

And the resulting table would look like this:

[1][1]
[1][1]
[1][1]
[1]

What's the easiest way to do this with MigLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two different panels for each column, with one column in each panel.

It gets a bit painful sometimes to work with layered panels in MigLayout, but absent any specific problems, this is the easiest.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a less-nested layout (since this is supposed to be one of the advantages of MigLayout), but I suppose this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridLayout` like:

```
   GridLayout layout=new GridLayout(4, 2);
```

Comment: The size needs to be dynamic.